# Are X and Y independent?

Tags: probability, dice

We roll two dice once. Let X denote the number of 1’s and Y the number of 6’s obtained. Are X and Y independent?

Comment: Don't think so... if $X=2$, can $Y$ be anything other than $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is $P((X=1) \cap (Y=2))=P(X=1)P(Y=2)$?

Comment: No, thanks for the example